# recognizing a button press in 'if statement'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I'm working on an iOS game where a text label appears and the player must hit the corresponding colored button. I'm trying to figure out how to format the if statement for recognizing if the button pressed is a match to the current text on screen. What I'm wanting to happen in this if statement is: if redText is showing AND redButton is pushed, add points. Otherwise game over. I'll copy/paste this statement for each of the four colors.

Here's the method as I have it currently, note "buttonPressed" means nothing, just a placeholder:

```
-(void)gameStatePlayNormal
{
    if (redText.hidden=NO && buttonPressed == redButton)
{
     score += 10;
}
    else
{
    gameState = kStateGameOver;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your feedback. :)

Comment: Does pressing the button call the `gameStatePlayNormal` method directly?

Comment: try placing tags on your buttons and checking if it is that button with the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a function that will be called when any of the buttons are pressed. Hook each button up to this function in your storyboard ("Touch Up Inside" event). Then you can intercept the sender.

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (redText.hidden=NO && [(UIButton *)sender isEqual:redButton]) {
        score += 10;
    }
    else {
        gameState = kStateGameOver;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(UIButton *)buttonPressed` should be `(UIButton *)sender`.

Comment: Woz that is getting me closer, however when I press the redButton in this situation the app terminates saying 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9027ea0'

Comment: Is it on a particular line? Are you sure you function is hooked up in your storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, they are hooked up as UIButton outlets not actions. I'm guessing thats the problem?

Comment: Yes, make sure you're function has `IBAction` as a return value and it should show up in your storyboard. Drag from this function in your view controller to "Touch Up Inside" with your red button.

Comment: I changed the buttons in storyboard to IBAction w/ touch up inside and linked them to the header file as redButton, blueButton, etc. However now in the buttonWasPressed method the redButton, blueButton, etc are being flagged as undeclared identifiers...

Comment: Even though you linked up the `IBAction`, you still have to link up the `IBOutlet`. Make sure you have something like `@property (non atomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *redButton;` in your .h file, and make the connection on your storyboard.

Comment: Yeah, the buttons have IBAction and UIButton declarations in the .h. I'm still getting a crash with buttons being undeclared identifiers if I press one during runtime.

Comment: Ok, I had made IBAction outlets for each button instead of linking the buttonWasPressed method to each button. That fixed the crash.

Comment: Thanks for your help Woz. That answered my original question. I'm encountering new problems but that is for another post. Cheers.